# How do I add a subdomain's sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

How do I add subdomain's sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools?

I have not added them in yet as it takes ages for Google to get around to crawling it and I would like to add the sitemaps as soon as knowing that it is the correct way.  BTW... I do not really want to have them separate for stats purposes and that I just wish to get them on Google's search engines.

Would it still work if I add them to my main domains sitemap? i.e. where I would like to place all sitemaps:

- `www.sm.example.com/sitemap1.php`
- `www.sm.example.com/sitemap2.php`

My other subdomains would be like this...

- `www.sub1.example.com`
- `www.sub2.example.com`
- and so on...

Comment: Sitemaps don't get search engines to index and rank pages effectively.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).   To get pages indexed and ranked well you *have to* link to the pages from other pages on your site.

Comment: Hi,Yes I understand this which is why I am giving Google and the like a hint to all pages so it can verify that 'they are' linked elsewhere on the site.  I think I will just try it and wait for a few months...

Comment: Add sub domain as separate site in search console then add the site map.

Comment: @AbuNooh Sounds like an answer. Short but still an answer! ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc thanks for the observation, will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your subdomain has other peculiarities from your main domain (it sounds like yours does) then add it as a new property in search console. Then you'll be able to treat like a domain and add sitemaps as well see search queries etc.

[Add new website property on search console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en).

Here's how to [combine and track your domain and subdomains together](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/05/tie-your-sites-together-with-property.html).

Comment: I cannot do much, so here is a dime! Cheers!!